# Can I separate the delegate logic to one class file only?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, uitextfield

I have many textfield, that only support using type "A"/"B"/"C" only, I wrote a textfield delegate to check the user input, including the length and the content that they inputed. But I want to separate the delegate from the class file. How can I do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

create another object and specify those all textfield delegate to that object

in property declaration use assign

then synthasize

textfield1.delegate=newobject;
textfield2.delegate=newobject;
textfield3.delegate=newobject;